# Onload fires no matter where I place it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right, I'm getting quite aggitated with this. I'm probably doing something wrong, but here's what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#somebutton').click(function () {
        openPage1();
    });
    $('#someotherbutton').click(function () {
        openPage2();
    });
});
var openPage1 = function () {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', 'someurl');
    $('#iframe').load(function () {
        $('#button').click();
    });
};
var openPage2 = function () {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', 'anotherurl');
    $('#iframe').load(function () {
        $('#anotherbutton').click();
    });
}
```

Whenever I click `somebutton` everything goes as expected. However when I click `someotherbutton`. The `.load()` from `openPage1()` is called first and I can't find a way to stop that. The `.load()` from `openPage1()` has a button with the same name, however on `openPage2()` I need to modify the contents before clicking the buttons.

I need to use `.load()` because I can't click the buttons before the document is ready.

Basically what I need is two seperate `.load()` instances on the same `iframe`, that don't fire off on each other.

Besides that, maybe my understanding of jQuery/JS is wrong, but shouldn't the `.load()` events only be listening after clicking the corresponding button?

Can someone help me out, this has been keeping me busy all afternoon.

Comment: I suggest looking up `.load()` on the jQuery docs...it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `has a button with the same name`. Do you actually mean `name` attribute or `id` attribute?

Comment: the same id attribute. @Bradm I did that, could you point me in a better direction?

Comment: .load() is for fetching a url and loading the results into a dom element. it is **NOT** an "onload" for elements, though it does provide that functionality when used properly. RTLM: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I edited your code, it missed some brackets. Hope this was a typo, otherwise copy the code back and it should work again. Keep in mind the `load()` comment too by Brad

Comment: The same `id` attribute for different elements is illegal and will lead to such behavior.

Comment: Never use an ID attribute twice in the DOM. It's illegal to have multiple identities in the real world, it should be illegal in web design.

Comment: No, it wasn't missing brackets. Re-edited

Comment: @Cristopher I don't have access to the pages that are using them, but it are simply two completely different pages that happen to use the same id for an ok button.

Comment: @MarcB @RenePot : there are two `load` functions : http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @Difusio, then you should punch their web developer in the face. Until then, use the `class` attribute for elements with similar purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing : `$('#iframe').load(function (){  $('#button').click();  });`, you are adding a listener on the load event, which will stay and be re-executed on each subsequent reload of the iframe.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Dt8c/) to demonstrate this : click on the "reload" button, and see how many times the "loaded" message appears in your console.

in your case, if you click on `#somebutton`, then on `#someotherbutton`, after the second click, you will have two handlers bound on the `load` event, and both will be triggered.

If you click 5 times on `#somebutton`, you should end up calling 5 times `$('#button').click()`.

If you want to execute it *once*, you can follow [Fred's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15526363/86072), or use jQuery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) binder :

```
$('#iframe').one('load', function(){  $('#button').click()  });
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Dt8c/1/) : 'loaded' should be displayed only once per click.

Comment: `one()`! That is a great idea. +1.

Comment: Most clarifying answer, and it made me realize that I made a spaghetti mess :D

Answer (score 4):

Try using on, and once loaded, unbind

```
$("#iframe").on("load", function(){
    $(this).off("load");
    $('#button').click();
});
```

That way you remove the handler you put up before the second button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try and replace the lines in both functions like this:

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {
    $('#anotherbutton').click();
};
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'anotherurl');
```

Otherwise it might be firing the event before the new event-handler has been set.

Answer (score 0):

<s>This isn't really an answer to your problem</s> Now it is an answer, but I think utilizing functions as they were intended could be beneficial here, i.e.:

```
//Utilize a single function that takes arguments
var openPage = function (frame, src, eventEl) {
    frame.attr('src', src);      // If you pass frame as a jQuery object, you don't
    frame.on("load", function(){ // need to do it again
        $(this).off("load");
        evEl.click(); //Same for your buttons
    });
}



//Simplify other code
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#somebutton').click(function () {
        openPage($("#iframe"),somehref,$("#buttonelement"));
    });
    $('#someotherbutton').click(function () {
        openPage($("#iframe"),anotherhref,$("#someotherbuttonelement"));
    });
});
```